# Can I replace this broken pipe under my kitchen sink?

Tags: kitchen-sink

This pipe under my kitchen sink has a big crack in the area circled in yellow. (It's on the back side so it isn't visible in the photo.) Can I simply unscrew the nut at the top that I circled in red to replace the pipe? I'm afraid to just go ahead and try in the fear that I will put my kitchen sink out of commission. I'm already ok with disconnecting the hand-tightened nut at the bottom.

[image: my broken pipe]

**Update:**

Success! I replaced the tailpiece with no problem. Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: Where is your siphon?

Comment: @Mast It's below the T connection. Look to the bottom right of the image and you'll see where the trap connects to the horizontal drain. This is normal on a double basin sink like you'll find in a kitchen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - that's a "tailpiece" - the new one may be too long, if so, they are made that way so you can cut them to fit - but there's also considerable space to slide them built into the connections, so don't overdo cutting them down.

Comment: Wrap the cracked tailpiece with some electrical tape until you have time to fix it.  It'll save you from having to empty the bucket +

Comment: Parafilm® is nice for that if you happen to have any (former lab rat.)

Comment: Since the drain is non-pressurized, the tape would be more than sufficient to redirect the water to the outflow. Just don't leave that as permanent solution because it'll eventually fail and the crack will also slowly get worse anyways.

Comment: The three comments above don't answer the question.

Comment: @Jennifer that might be why they're comments and not answers.

Comment: @JACK Thanks for the electrical tape tip.

Comment: @Jennifer There was no need to answer the question because Ecnerwal nailed it and no need for duplication. The comments are there to assist in the completion of  the OP's project.

Comment: If he leaves the tailpiece too long it will block the outflow from the right-hand sink.

Comment: @David42 There are "stops"  in the tee to prevent that from happening.

Comment: The first task must always be to answer the question.  Anything else is just an assumption that that something else is wanted.  At the worst, noise.

Comment: @Jennifer look in the mirror. Note that the question **was** answered first, and your comments are looking a lot like noise. Particularly this one thrown in 6 weeks later...

Comment: @Ecnerwal whatever doesn't answer the question -- or makes assumptions about what the REAL question is -- is noise